# Accessing original name of file uploaded as a file parameter

Tags: bash, variables, jenkins, parameters, environment-variables

I have a simple parametrized Jenkins job that takes a file parameter. However when I try to get its original name in the build step I get a bad substitution error on bash.

Here is the file param [image: Job File Param]

Here is the build step [image: Build step]

Here are the instructions on getting the name [image: Instructions]

The error message I get is:

```
00:00:00.007 /tmp/jenkins4136900049932701838.sh: 2: /tmp/jenkins4136900049932701838.sh: Bad substitution
00:00:00.011 Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

***This is more of a bash question than a Jenkins question, but I wanted to give context to what I am doing.***

Any suggestions why I am not able to dereference the variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your file name does not contain valid characters to be created as a variable.

"." nor "/" are not valid characters in a bash variable so the system cannot save your file name as a variable.

See also since this has been answered before: [Access file parameter in jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232347/access-file-parameter-in-jenkins)

Comment: In that case the Jenkins help documentation is wrong because they give precisely that example. ${abc.zip}, see screenshot in my post above.

Comment: haha, well if there can be one thing said of jenkins, their documentation generally is shit.